# Drawing sprite with additional alpha channel

Tags: sprite, alpha, direct3d

I can draw image with alpha channel fine,
but can't modify alpha channel via color parameter.

Tried this:

```
d3dImage->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND|D3DXSPRITE_SORT_DEPTH_BACKTOFRONT|D3DXSPRITE_DO_NOT_ADDREF_TEXTURE);
```

I'm using sprite to render rectangle and images:

```
void DrawRect(float x, float y, int width, int height, DWORD color)
{
    imgPosition.x = x;
    imgPosition.y = y;

    imgSize.left = 0;
    imgSize.right = width;
    imgSize.top = 0;
    imgSize.bottom = height;

    d3dImage->Draw(texWhite, &imgSize, NULL, &imgPosition, color);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with 8-bit textures only.